# How to read a unicode file as extended ascii

Tags: python, unicode

If I read a unicode file using the following:

```
f = open(r'file.txt','rU')
raw = f.read()
```

how can I cause the file to be read as extended ascii, that is convert \xc3\xaa to ê correctly and convert all non-displayable characters to a default character (say ?).

I also have the following:

```
# Create a file called sitecustomize.py in c:\python27\Lib\site-packages.
import sys
sys.setdefaultencoding('iso-8859-1')
```

which I'm not sure whether I need to change.

For some reason I can't paste ê into the python console (dos in windows) put I can do:

```
>>> s = u'La Pe\xf1a'
>>> print s
La Peña
```

Anybody have any idea how to do this?

Comment: There is no such thing as extended ASCII.

Comment: You are touching upon several different issues here. I think you need to go and read the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html).

Comment: Moreover, Windows and unicode in the console are notoriously unhappy with one another.

Comment: Don't change the default encoding.  Many libraries rely on the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in python2

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open('file.txt','rU',encoding='utf8')
```

in py3 just

```
f = open('file.txt','rU',encoding='utf8')
```

To clear up confusion, there's no such thing as "unicode file". Unicode is a mathematical abstraction and files are bytes on your disc. In order to convert these bytes to an internal memory representation of unicode codepoints, python needs to know how to interpret them. This interpretation is called "encoding" and from your post you appear to use "utf8". So you have to tell that to python.